# Removed hyphen from word_separators, ctrl+d no longer makes sense

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I removed the `-` from the `word_separators` setting, and that works fine.

But <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> on the word `a` still matches the "a" in `a-b`, I don't want it to do that anymore.

It's because <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> wraps your search with regex boundaries `\b`, and `-` is still considered a boundary.

Is there anything I can do to now make <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> not consider `-` a boundary anymore.

EDIT: picture:
[image]

The "a" in `a-b` should not be highlighted, as `a-b` is a single variable name in this language, which is why I removed the `-` from `word_separators`

More clarification: If I'm trying to replace all instance of the variable `a`, I don't want it matching against parts of other variables, like the "a" in `a-b`.

Comment: Can you post an example of what's happening and what's the expected editor behavior ?

Comment: @Amir Sure, I added a picture to my question

Comment: why don't you find 'a' by selecting a with the white space. Or by doing Ctrl + f to find this regex pattern `a ?`

Comment: @Amir Selecting with whitespace isn't what I want to do, and that regex pattern is worse than what `ctrl+d` is doing now. That would match any `a` character anywhere

Comment: `word_separators` from the [*manual*](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html): "In some contexts, the text might be tokenized based on other criteria (for example, the syntax definition rules)."

Comment: Did you highlight `a` before doing the multiple selection? I know highlighting before selecting will search for the selection, not an exact match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I can tell from some informal experimenting while answering your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23999800/1426065), the `"word_separators"` setting seems to primarily relevant when double-clicking to select words. For example, I have the following words in a file:

[image: foobar]

and my `word_separators` list is `` ./\\()\"'-:,;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?$ ``, so it includes `-` and `/` but not `_`. If I put my cursor in the first `foo` (without selecting the whole word first) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, I get

[image: foobar2]

and if I continue hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for several more times, I get

[image: foobar3]

so only the "individual words" are selected - `foo_bar` is not, nor is `foobar`. However, if I set `word_separators` to `` .\\()\"':,;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?$ `` (removing `-` and `/`) I get the same results when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly:

[image: foobar4]

`-` and `/` are still treated as word separators, even though I removed them from the list. If I add `_` to the `word_separators` list, the results are the same, and only one obvious conclusion can be drawn: `word_separators` is ignored by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (`find_under_expand`).

---

However, the `word_separators` list **IS** used when double-clicking to select a word. With the list like this: `` .\\()\"'_:,;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?$ `` (missing `-` and `/`, but with `_`), double-clicking on `foo` in each word in turn gives the following:

[image: foobar5]

[image: foobar6]

[image: foobar7]

[image: foobar8]

Interestingly, double-clicking on the very first `foo` gives

[image: foobar9]

indicating that the "box" highlighting of similar selections is not paying attention to `word_separators`.

---

When using **`Find -> Find...`** to search, `word_separators` is ignored. When nothing is selected and `foo` is entered into the search box (non-regex search), the following matches are highlighted:

[image: foobar10]

This is the same regardless of whether `-`, `/`, and/or `/` are in `word_separators` or not.

If `"Whole Word"` is set in the options, the results are a bit different, but again they don't change regardless of whether `-`, `/`, and/or `/` are in `word_separators`:

[image: foobar11]

---

### **TL;DR**

So, the conclusion is that `word_separators` is only in effect when double-clicking to select a word. Using a **`Find`** dialog or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (`find_under_expand` command) relies on some internal separator list, which apparently can't be altered (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24000490/1426065)).

---

#### A little bit more

Some info I forgot to add earlier: `word_separators` is also used by some plugins for various sorts of things, such as creating/modifying/otherwise working with selections, doing programmable completions, find and replace, and other sorts of stuff.

Comment: Do you think this is something that should be in sublime by default? (Having `ctrl+d` listen to the `word_separators` setting) Maybe I should mention this to the sublime guys as a feature suggestion?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar - this has (kind of) already been addressed - see this [issue](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/212) in SublimeText/Issues. Although, this might be sufficiently different that a new issue could be created...