# How to edit built in command behavior

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want to edit `find_under_expand` (`ctrl+d`) to consider hyphenated words, as single words. So when I try to replace all instance of var `a`, it shouldn't match substrings of "a" in words like `a-b`, which it currently does.

[image]

I'm assuming `find_under_expand` wraps your current selection in regex boundaries like this: `\ba\b`

I need it to wrap in something like this: `\b(?<!-)a(?!-)\b`

Is the `find_under_expand` command's source available to edit? Or do I have to rewrite the whole thing? I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime's commands are implemented in one of several ways: as [macros](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html), as [plugins](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html), and internally as part of the compiled program (probably as C++). The default macros and plugins can be found in the `Packages/Default` directory in ST2 (where `Packages` is the directory opened when selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**), or zipped in the `Installed Packages/Default.sublime-package` file in ST3, extractable using @skuroda's excellent [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin, available via Package Control. Macros have `.sublime-macro` extensions, while plugins are written in Python and have `.py` extensions.

I searched all through the `Defaults` package in ST3 (things are generally the same as in ST2), and was unable to find a macro or `.py` file that included the `find_under_expand` command, or `FindUnderExpand`, which is the convention when naming command classes in plugins. Therefore, I strongly suspect that this command is internal to Sublime, probably written in C++ and linked into the executable or in a `.dll|.dylib|.so` library.

So, it doesn't look like there's an existing file that you could easily modify to adjust for your negative lookahead/lookbehind patterns (I assume that's what those are, my regex is a bit rusty...). Instead, you'll have to implement your own plugin from scratch that reads the `"word_separators"` value in your settings file, which the current implementation of `find_under_expand` doesn't seem to be doing, judging from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974288/removed-hyphen-from-word-separators-ctrld-no-longer-makes-sense) and my own testing. Theoretically, this shouldn't be too terribly difficult - you can just open up a quick panel where the user enters the pattern/regex to be searched for, and you can just iterate through the current view looking for matches and highlighting/selecting them.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome answer, lots of detailed information, thank you.