# Double click highlight variable Sublime Text 3 include $

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I wanted ST3 to include the "$" when selecting PHP files so I edited `word_separators` by removing `$` as such :

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

And now it highlight the whole varibale including the "$" when double clicking a variable. However, now Sublime is not matching/outlining those variables using the default `match_selection` functionality.

Any thoughts on this? Is there a setting I am missing. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24001230/1426065) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974288/removed-hyphen-from-word-separators-ctrld-no-longer-makes-sense) for an in-depth look at the effect of changing `word_separators` and various find and select options. Long story short, altering `word_separators` changes the behavior of double-clicking, as you noted, but other operations, including `match_selection`, rely on an internal word separators list that apparently can't be altered by the user. So, when you double-click to select a PHP variable, you'll get the `$` selected, but other instances of the variable won't be highlighted. They **will** be selected when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to make multiple selections, however:

[image: $wp_error ctrl+d]

Additionally, when using the **`Find`** dialog, other instances will be highlighted:

[image: Find $wp_error]

So, to address your original problem, if you need to see all the instances of the currently-selected variable, set `"find_selected_text": true` in your user preferences, double-click to select your variable of interest, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on OS X) to view all occurrences. Just make sure you don't have the regex search button selected, as `$` has a special meaning in regexes.

Comment: What theme are you using in those screenshots?

Comment: @wkm I'm using my [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), available on Package Control, for syntax highlighting. I also use the [Soda](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Soda) theme for theming UI elements like buttons and so forth, as I haven't adapted Neon to it yet. If you use Neon, and end up having any questions or anything, just send me an [issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues/new) on Github and I'll get right back to you.