# Word Separator + CTRL D in PHP

Tags: php, settings, sublimetext3

Using Sublim Text 3 on some PHP files, I modified my settings like this :

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

(Just removed the $ sign)

Now when I double click a variable, the whole variable is selected including the $ sign, same behaviour with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (to select a word).

But if I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> again, in order to select the next occurence :

- it doesn't work if I selected my word with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- it works if I selected my word with my mouse

Of course, if I don't modify my word separator settings, it works as intended.

Is it a bug or did I miss something ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25852673) helped me : word separator does not affect everything, sadness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double click highlight variable Sublime Text 3 include $](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613424/double-click-highlight-variable-sublime-text-3-include)